# Threads from slaves not captured in the JTL files in a distributed test

Tags: testing, jmeter, distributed

In a distributed test with a thread group having 100 threads and 3 slaves. I see that in the test it generated 300 threads to execute the test as the thread group is executed by each of the slaves. However, when I capture the results using a JTL, it only reports 100 active threads through the test duration. Is it an issue with the JTL or is there some configuration that we need to do to get the results properly?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all the nodes (client and servers) :

-are running exactly the same version of JMeter.

-are using the same version of Java on all systems. Using different versions of Java may work but is discouraged.

-have a valid keystore for RMI over SSL, or you have disabled the use of SSL.

If the test uses any data files, note that these are not sent across by the client so make sure that these are available in the appropriate directory on each server.

Once you have checked above, run a small test and check the output is as expected.

Ref:-https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html

Comment: I have all this same across the Master and Slave. I only have an issue with the Active threads over time graph from the JTL. It is capturing data properly for the requests.

Comment: Since, it is reporting only 100 threads. It looks line only one slave machine data. Can you run a simple test for 1 thread on each slave which can generate only 3 rows and check if it is getting consolidated correctly. Is there any error reporting on any of the slaves or master.?